# How to tell whether your Betta fish is eating his feeder?

Tags: fish, feeding, betta

So, I am needing to travel to visit family. I have a feeder for my Betta fish; it's the type that sits on the bottom and the fish nibbles off of. However, my fish is used to eating off the surface, and to me feeding him. (He actually swims to the surface of the aquarium when he sees me in the morning).

I did a partial block, since a whole block was too much for the length of time that I'm gone. However, that makes it a bit harder to tell, since the edges on one side aren't exactly "even."

I do have a family member that can check on him periodically. However, neither of us know exactly how to tell whether my Betta fish is actually eating the feeder or not. Is there a good way to tell?

Comment: I was a little confused by the title, maybe a language thing, for me as not native speaker a feeder is a person who feeds fish ;)

Comment: @Allerleirauh I was also confused because it's also not my native language, but I assumed even other thing that feeder was an automatic equipment that you fill with food and it opens once a day to release a small portion of food into the water. But I searched online and feeder is indeed the name of these slow-release food blocks ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question: you can't.
However, here are a few tips:

- if you have seen him eat from the feeder, then he will probably do it when you're not watching;
- the Betta's mouth is oriented upwards. In its natural environment, he catches insects on the surface and feeding from below is not natural to him;
- a fish is not a dog: it can easily spend a few days without eating. If you're away for a few days only, or if your friend can come every few days (even once a week) and can feed him, it's OK;
- a Betta doesn't need a full aquarium paraphernalia. He can breath at the surface using his labyrinth and does OK in room temperature water. Your friend can keep him at his place in a simple jar and feed him while you're away.

;-)

Comment: If the "without equipment" is really only for some days, this answer is okay :) But because some bettas need to life this way their whole life, I want to add: only a few days!!!

Comment: Great answer! I do agree with @Allerleirauh  I would not recommend removing the fish from a heated, filtered tank at all, but no more than a few days if absolutely necessary. If I’m gone for more than 4 days, I get a friend to feed the betta, as suggested here!